# What are valid arguments for the -p option in a chain code deploy in hyperledger fabric?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger

In particular, I have chaincode that is stored on github and I would like to executive this chaincode in my local cluster of notes.  What is the easiest way of getting my local cluster to pull down remote chaincode and execute it.

Answer (score 1):

The Hyperledger fabric chaincode deploy CLI command is described [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/docs/protocol-spec.md#6313-chaincode-deploy). Essentially, you give it the path to the chaincode on your local filesystem starting at one of the values of the $GOPATH environment variable. For example:

```
./peer chaincode deploy -p github.com/hyperledger/fabric/example/chaincode/go/chaincode_example02 -c '{"Function":"init", "Args": ["a","100", "b", "200"]}'
```

Comment: also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37433618/how-to-use-a-chaincode-thats-not-on-github